# VBA works with F8/F5 but fails when called from button/SUB

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

The basic code below works when I F8/F5 in the visual basic window. Some of it fails when I call it using a button in a worksheet, or from within another SUB (my final goal).

The part highlighted between '####' fails. It doesn't move the label below. It's as though it skips that line. The same code for `ChartDataLablesMARVEL` works every time.

I've tried unselecting the previous selection, or simply selecting the `ChartDataLablesDC` first and then repositioning it. Again, doesn't work when called by a button or SUB.

I'm a novice with VBA, and I'm stumped. I don't see why it would react in that way.

Any help or ideas very much appreciated?

Thanks

```
Public Sub LastDataLabelsMARVELABOVE()
'Formatting the position pf the last data labels in my chart 

Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim ChartPointsDC As Points
Dim ChartPointsMARVEL As Points
Dim ChartDataLablesDC As DataLabel
Dim ChartDataLablesMARVEL As DataLabel

Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 11").Chart

Set ChartPointsMARVEL = MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
Set ChartDataLablesMARVEL = ChartPointsMARVEL(ChartPointsMARVEL.Count).DataLabel
Set ChartPointsDC = MyChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points
Set ChartDataLablesDC = ChartPointsDC(ChartPointsDC.Count).DataLabel


With MyChart
    With ChartDataLablesMARVEL
        .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    End With
**'#########THIS PART IS NOT WORKING WHEN CALLED BY A BUTTON OR WITHIN A SUB    
    With ChartDataLablesDC
        .Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
    End With
'##########**
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(ChartPointsMARVEL.Count).DataLabel.Select
            Selection.Left = 466
MyChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(ChartPointsDC.Count).DataLabel.Select
            Selection.Left = 466
End Sub
```

### EDIT - 14/03/19

I reworked my WITH statement, thanks to advice from @TED_D and have managed to make the code run correctly when using a button on the sheet.

However, and there always seems to be one, I still encounter the same original problem when I call this code as part of another SUB. The `ChartDataLablesDC` moving it below (or above) fails. The MARVEL label code moves the labels above or below, with no problems. It's just the DC one that fails.

My goal is to wrap it all up in one SUB where I call two ALL LABELS subs and then the FINAL LABELS code above.

ALL LABELS

```
Sub MARVELLabelsAbove()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 11").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    Selection.AutoText = True
End Sub
Sub DCLabelsBelow()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 11").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
    Selection.AutoText = True
End Sub
```

I'm quite happy that I've managed to make my code work from buttons on the sheet, but I'd like to understand why the last part of the FINAL LABELS codesfails when called with my ALL LABELS code.

Comment: is "Chart 11" always on the sheet where you press your button?  or is it on the active sheet when other parts of your code are running?  Does other parts of your code switch the active sheet on you?

Comment: not for nothing, but you only have one dot operator used by the `With` in the entirety of the doubly nested `With` block (both of the doubly nested with blocks have one dot operator each). In fact within the `With MyChart` (outer `With`) you have referenced `MyChart` unnecessarily.  Generally, one would use the `With` when there are several references to an Object's members (methods & properties) especially if the object reference is derived (to avoid declaring and storing the calculated reference in a variable or recalculating the reference several times).

Comment: Chart 11 is on the active sheet. The buttons are on the same sheet as Chart 11. I do not go between sheets.

Comment: @TedD. It's probably overkill and incorrect, but my VBA level is quite basic so I ended up with this and it was working when running it on it's own through the windo, but now partially fails when using a button. I'll try to amend it and see what happens.

Comment: Here is another take on the `With` statement. Suppose you needed to give a person directions to several places starting from your home. The first part of the directions are how to get out of your neighborhood and they are the same regardless of where the rest of the directions take them. That is the `With Get Out of The Neighbor hood` and **dot** `.from there ...`. So if an Object has a member  (the member can be an object with members ...) then each dot operator accesses its member. `With Object` followed by any dot member name, `.Property` `.Method`, is the same as `Object.Property`

Comment: Use care with nested `With` blocks. There are two scenarios for using Nested blocks. The inner with is, or is not, a "dot member". When the inner `With` is `With .Member_of_Outer` then the outer With could simply have been replaced by `With Object_O.Member_of_Outer` unless, and this applies to either scenario, some of the code inside the nested `With` blocks is a dot operator referencing the outer `With Object_O`. This is only possible to do if the inner `With Object_I` does not also have the dot member. If both Obj_O and Obj_I have a Value member, then `.Value` will reference Obj_I's value.